# TCPDump and TCPReplay to record and replay requests to application servers

Tags: tcpdump, tcpreplay

Can TCPDump and TCPReplay be used to record(tcpdump) network traffic coming in to a application server/webserver/queue application etc., and then replayed using the dump on TCPReplay?

Let's say I setup a apache server and use TCPDump to capture the entire network traffic and dump it to a file. Now I run apache in a different machine and want to replay the traffic to this new apache server using the file. How can I achieve this?

I especially want to understand how TCPReplay would work in such a scenario. i.e. how would syn/ack responses work for TCP. How would a new a connection etc. be initiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use Tcpreplay to replay traffic to a server. TCP sessions have random sequence numbers, and are fully stateful. Replaying previously recorded TCP traffic will be ignored by a server.

Comment: Thanks @fredk I just wanted confirmation. I understand the details regarding the reason from Aaron Turner's respose

Answer (score 1):

Fred is right.  Also, this question is answered in the Tcpreplay FAQ: http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/FAQ#Doestcpreplaysupportsendingtraffictoaserver